# How to use RatingBar in my music player i created for android?

Tags: android, android-music-player

I have created a music player for android for my final year project. It has the basic functions like play, next, previous and also a scroll-bar to select songs from the playlist.

I wanted to use a rating bar to allow the user to set ratings for the songs but if i set the rating for 1 song and then choose another song from the playlist, **the same rating is set for that song, too**.

How do i make it set different ratings for different songs?

Comment: Sounds like you're reusing the View...can you post some code and/or give more details for where the rating bar live and where/when you're setting it's value?

Comment: need to see some code to answer properly ...

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm gonna ship this...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a callback for when a song changes? Basically, we'd need to see some code, but you're going to want to reset the rating back to 2 stars, or whatever the default number of stars is. Then you will want to use the [OnRatingBarChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener.html) to save the ratings to a database. It appears that the "MediaPlayer" class has an [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html#onCompletion%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29) to tell when a track is finished.

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener barListener = 
    new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromTouch) {
                // Do your database stuff here
            }

        }
```

and then your stuff for the onCompletion

```
//mp is the reference to your media player
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {           
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // Do what you need to do to reset the rating bar. Might need to make a public reference or create a way for this inner class to access the rating bar.

        }           
    });
```

Comment: I thought I'd need a database for this. I don't want to use a databse so i guess I'll just let this go.

Answer (score 0):

I think, set the rate of rating bar to your default value when there is a song change, `OnClickListener` on previous and next on your activity.

```
ratingbar.setRating(3); //For three stars
```

And save the rate of song with `OnRatingBarChange`.